# Cron running too frequently

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following cron:

`* * */2 * * pip install boto3 && pip install python-dateutil && pip install pytz && /usr/bin/python2 /home/ubuntu/AMI_Cleanup.py >> /home/ubuntu/AMI_Cleanup.log 2>&1`

And, it is running every 30 seconds or so...I cannot figure out why and have tried everything. I ran a `ps axjf` and it is indeed the cron running (not something I was unaware about). Is my schedule wrong? I expect it to run every two days...

Comment: I am setting it up by calling `sudo crontab -e` if that makes a difference..

Comment: This setup runs “At every minute on every 2nd day-of-month.” See this on [Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*/2_*_*), which I find rather useful.

Comment: Voted to close, not a programming question,  but one about how to use `cron`. Better off on [unix.se] **or** [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in crontab means "every" - so this expression means "on every minute of every hour of every other day". Instead, you should specify some minute and hour combination. E.g., to run this cron job at 2AM every other day, you could use:

```
0 2 */2 * * pip install boto3 && pip install python-dateutil && pip install pytz && /usr/bin/python2 /home/ubuntu/AMI_Cleanup.py >> /home/ubuntu/AMI_Cleanup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Seems to be working now. I will update to accept after it runs at the expected time